# Conteo de Objetos con Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

tengo el siguiente codigo de opencv para realizar conteo de objetos:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

camino= "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg"
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/123.jpg")

grises= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

bordes= cv2.Canny(grises, 100, 200)

_, ctns, = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
print ('Numero de contornos es ', len(ctns))
texto= 'Contornos encontrados ' + str(len(ctns))

cv2.putText(img, texto, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,  
    (255, 0, 0), 1)


cv2.imshow('Bordes', bordes)
cv2.imshow('Imagen', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

me sale este error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de
>   Objetos/contornoscongranny.py", line 13, in 
>       cv2.drawContours(img, ctns, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function
>   'cv::drawContours'

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra al recibir la informacion de la función `findContours`, tienes el orden incorrecto. Primero son los contornos y segundo la matriz de herarquía.

```html
ctns, _, = cv2.findContours(bordes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Te dejo un [enlace](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) para que puedas revisar la documentación.

Un saludo.